# Get the value of a specific row and specific column from datagrid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2012

This is the code that does the job in GridView but not working in DataGrid

```
Dim x as string = GridView1.rows(e.rowindex).cells(2).text  (Working)    
Dim x as string = DataGrid1.rows(e.rowindex).cells(2).text  (Not Working)
```

I need to work with the DataGrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and see if it works for you.

```
  Dim x = DataGrid1.Rows(e.rowindex).Cells(2).Value.ToString()
```

Comment: I tried it and it didn't  work
But I got something else worked
"Dim x as string = e.item.cells(2).text"